# In using jQuery UI's toggle, what exactly can we set on the 'option' argument?

Tags: jquery-ui

The documentation says: "A object/hash including specific options for the effect."  Checked the documentation on Effect, same description.

While the example suggests something like this:

> { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };

I'm still curious what else can be done. Any ideas?

Comment: Toggle isn't very complex, I'd be surprised if it took anything other than size, or animation-specific arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle options take only animation specific arguments. You can find an overview of these arguments on the [jQuery UI suite website](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods) of course you have to included it, to make use of effects.